# DataSource configuration in IBM Websphere used in application

Tags: java, websphere

My application is successfully deployed on test environment on IBM Websphere 6.1. I need to deploy the same application on my local machine. I am able to install my web application on IBM Websphere using admin console. But I am not able to configure datasource. Datasource is provided in the property file which is used successfully in test environment. Now, where do I configure datasource in IBM websphere, which will be used by my application. Datasource is not configured in web.xml or ibm-web-bnd.xmi. After deployment, I am getting following error in log files.

> Connection Pooling Set up failed javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   Context: 01HW357911Node01Cell/nodes/01HW357911Node01/servers/server1,
>   name: jdbc/SupplierNetDataSource: First component in name
>   SupplierNetDataSource not found. [Root exception is
>   org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound:
>   IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0

I also created datasource in IBM Websphere admin console in resources successfully. But same is not used by my application. 
I also created {Name Space Binding] in Environment->Naming path in admin console. But still same error is coming.

I also tried using tnsnames.ora file for datasource name, but was not successful.

Is there any way, to check the JNDI configured on test/dev unix server which can be replicated on local?

Comment: In your console, go to Resources, JDBC Providers and setup one.  Inside the new provider, setup a JDBC DataSource, pointing to your database.  Test the connection from the console, make that work first.  Then make sure the JNDI name defined here matches what you declared in your EAR.  The names must match.  So it should be jndi/SupplierNetDataSource, not jdbc/SupplierNetDataSource I think (I can't see your EAR files).

Comment: I have setup a jdbc datasource pointing to my mb and tested successfully. Also, I changed dataSource name in property file as
com.acg.dataSourceName = jndi/SupplierNetDataSource
However, still same error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere 6.1 reached end of service more than 5 years, do yourself a huge favor, move up to version 8.55 or 9, both of which are currently supported.  When you said "datasource is provided in the property file...", I'm assuming you're referring to the procedure described in [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_config_prop_jdbcprovider_ds.html).  If so, you'll need to start the wsadmin command line tool and execute the steps indicated to create the datasource.  Note, after running `AdminTask.applyConfigProperties`, you'll need to save the config using `AdminConfig.save()` and restart the server.  As you mentioned, you can also create the datasource from the admin console, using the values in the datasource properties file as values, but you'll also need to create a JDBC provider to go with the datasource.  If you're still having problems after applying the properties file, posting the contents of it here (less any userids/passwords) here would be the next step.

Comment: Following is  property file values com.acg.productLibrary= ALSTOMDBA. com.acg.schemaName = ALSTOMDBA.
com.acg.dbType = ORACLE
com.acg.connectionStringDev = 
com.acg.oracleUserId = 
com.acg.oraclePassword = 
com.acg.dataSourceName = jndi/SupplierNetDataSource
I have created a jdbc provider for datsource named SupplierNetDataSource using admin console. It is connecting successfully. However, same is not used by my application. In logs, getting null connection.
On login page, I am getting following error: Error 500: com.andrewscg.frameworks.RTC_global (initialization failure)

Comment: That's not a properties file that WebSphere can process to create a datasource.  You said that you have created both a jdbcprovider and a datasource using the admin console, what's the purpose of the properties file then?  I think you're getting confused by the sequence required to configure this, the properties file seems to be superfluous.  1) from admin console, create jdbc provider for Oracle.  2) from admin console, create a datasource that uses above jdbc provider, with jndiName of jdbc/SupplierNetDataSource.  3) save config, restart server

Comment: The application reads datasource name from properties file. Now, IBM websphere will look for the database using data source name. Datasource name (containing values like url, id, password etc) is created using admin console in ibm websphere. But same is not used by the application.

Comment: From the admin console, you've created a JDBCProvider for Oracle, and a Datasource with JNDI name " jndi/SupplierNetDataSource" using that JDBCProvider.  You can press the "Test Connection" button on the datasource panel and the connection works?  And your application is looking up "jndi/SupplierNetDataSource"?

Comment: Application is looking for datasource named "jndi/SupplierNetDataSource". Error coming is "First component in name jndi/SupplierNetDataSource not found". logs are already present in the question. Same error is still coming.

Answer (score 0):

which scope did you created jdbc/SupplierNetDataSource data source ?